# Gitlabci: how make dynamic next stage?

Tags: gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery, cicd

I have pipeline case

Exist 2 files:
.base_integration_test.yml - Integration tests without Kafka
.base_integration_test_with_kafka.yml - Integration tests with Kafka

```
include:
# PRODUCT
  - project: 'gitlabci/integration-test'
    ref: dev_v2
    file: 
      - 'spark/.base_integration_test.yml'
      - 'spark/.base_integration_test_with_kafka.yml'
```

scenario selection in the preliminary step

need choose

or

```
.base_integration_test: 
  variables:
    COVERAGE_SOURCE: "./src"
  extends: .base_integration_test
```

or

```
.base_integration_test_with_kafka:
  variables:
    COVERAGE_SOURCE: "./src"
  extends: .base_integration_test_with_kafka
```

How to do it better?

p.s.

how tried

make stage

```
prepare_test:
  image: $CI_REGISTRY/platform/docker-images/vault:1.8
  stage: prepare_test
  script:
    - export CICD_KAFKA_HOST=$(cat test/fixtures.py | grep KAFKA_HOST)
    - >
      if [ "$CICD_KAFKA_HOST" != "" ]; then
        export CICD_KAFKA_HOST="true"
      else
        export CICD_KAFKA_HOST="false"
        echo "CICD_KAFKA_HOST=$CICD_KAFKA_HOST" >> dotenv.env
      fi
    - env | sort -f
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv:
        - dotenv.env
    expire_in: 6000 seconds
```

in next stage

```
integration_test:
  variables:
    COVERAGE_SOURCE: "./src"
  extends: .base_integration_test
  dependencies:
    - prepare_test
  rules:
    - if: $CICD_KAFKA_HOST == "false"
    - when: never
```

but integration_test doesn't even show up on startup pipeline

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In your example, `.base_integration_test` extends itself. Also, `.base_integration_test__with_kafka` extends `.base_integration_test_with_kafka`, which is also confusing and hard to read. In any case, the jobs in a pipeline are determined at pipeline start, which is nothing you can change, if that is your intention. As workarounds, you could skip a job or you could trigger a child pipeline.

Comment: in stage prepare_test decide need test test with kafka or not, for example in next job i write job with rule, but if variable not variable is not defined job not worked

Comment: added not worked variant

Comment: Okay, I think I know what's going on: `rules` determine whether a job is included in a pipeline. This is determined when the pipeline is created. Nothing you do inside of a job (which comes later) has any influence on that.